# Binomial Random Variable Problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Person $A$ and Person $B$ play a best of $5$ rock paper scissors match. If a person wins $3$ matches, they win the whole game. The probability person $A$ wins a match is $p = 0.6$; the probability person $B$ wins a match is $q = 1 - p = 0.4$. Compute the probability Person $A$ defeats Person $B$ in $3$ matches (i.e. wins $3$ times in a row).

I am stuck between two answers

a) ${5 \choose 3} p^3 q^2$

b) ${2 \choose 2} p^3 $

I think the former one signifies the probability $A$ wins $3$ games and loses $2$, but this doesn't take into consideration the constraint of only $3$ matches being played, it just means he has $3$ wins out of $5$ total matches.

The latter takes this into account I think, since we have three slots with the last one being taken with a win ( _ _ w), so there are $2$ choose $2$ ways to order the $2$ remaining wins. Not sure if my thinking is right, please clarify if I am on the wrong track!

Answer (score 2):

For a), you are right:

> "I think the former one signifies the probability A wins 3 games and loses 2, but this doesn't take into consideration the constraint of only 3 matches being played, it just means he has 3 wins out of 5 total matches."

It's just the probability A wins the game without the 3 match rule.

b) is the correct answer. You only care about the first 3 games which are played, and A has to win all of them. The probability of this is ${3\choose3}p^3=p^3$.

Although it doesn't make a difference to the value of your answer, ${3\choose3}$ would make more sense than ${2\choose2}$, as you're choosing the 3 wins from a set of 3 wins where order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The probability that Player A wins $3$ matches and loses $2$ matches is $p^3q^2$, and there are ${5 \choose 3}$ ways in which this could happen. Therefore, the probability that Player A wins $3$ of $5$ matches (in any order) is $p^3q^2{5 \choose 3}$.

If Player A must win in $3$ games, you may ignore the fact that it was originally supposed to be "best of 5". Three games were played, and $3$ were won by Player A. The probability of this happening is $p^3$, and there is exactly $1$ distinct way to order these wins. ${2 \choose 2} = 1$, so this would be equivalent to choice **b**.